# insert_text signal connect in Vala for Gtk.Entry

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm learning Vala and trying to build the simple application where if user enter something in `Gtk.Entry()`, it'll going to be printed into terminal. This is the code that I wrote to create the Entry in Vala.

```
var entry = new Gtk.Entry() {
  margin = 10
};
```

But, I don't know how to connect the signal with `entry`. So, whenever user entered something in Entry, it'll print to the terminal.

I tried this. But, not working for me.

```
entry.insert_text.connect((string text, int length, ref int position) => {
  stdout.printf("a");
});
```

I'm getting compilation error with above signal connect.

Comment: I think you might really want the `changed` signal, but what error message are you getting from the compiler? The `insert_text` signal is for people who paste text in to the Editable widget

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @AlThomas. Yes, `changed` is the signal actually I want. Works.